# What type of Codeigniter hook point would be suitable?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the same bit of code, that I want to execute at certain points in every action in every controller in my Codeigniter project. Which hook points would be the correct ones to use?

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

        // Execute first hook here

        $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);

        // Execute second hook here

    }

}
```

I am looking for two answers: the first answer for the first hook and the second for the second hook please. Thanks.

The hooks manual page is here and the hook points are explained at the bottom, but I can't figure out which ones are correct for my script.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: it seems after looking at your given hooks link.  none of hook fit to your requirement :(

Comment: alas, thats what i thought too... i cant believe codeigniter has such a limiting set of hook points? it's still early enought in the project to move over to cakephp if that has the features i require...

Comment: have you seen Yii ? As per me, Yii much btter than CakePHP

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? Are you looking to execute code before and after the function `index()` is called? Or are you looking for a hook that can be executed in the middle of a controller function?

Comment: Yes, please explain what you're trying to accomplish. You can probably use a parent controller, or your constructor. Give us more info and we can help. What will your hooks do? I'll tell you 'the CodeIgniter way'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CodeIgniter events library that seems like what you are looking for: 
https://github.com/ericbarnes/CodeIgniter-Events